# $f \in L^p(\Omega) \Rightarrow$ that exist a ball $B_R \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ that $\int_{\Omega \backslash B_R}|f|^p < \varepsilon$.

Tags: analysis

Let $f \in L^p(\Omega)$ and $\varepsilon >0$. Show that exist a ball $B_R \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\int_{\Omega \backslash B_R}|f|^p < \varepsilon$.

Comment: What is $\Omega$ ? An open set ? The ball has to be included in $\Omega$ ? Did you try with dominated convergence theorem ?

Comment: Also, you should ask a question rather than state an exercise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$\int_\Omega = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{\Omega \cap \{x: n-1 \le |x| < n\}}$$